# Telegram Bot API Edit Media Group Inline Keyboard

Tags: telegram-bot

In telegram while adding MediaGroup to chat, bot receives separate images in serial updates with `fileId` and `mediaGroupId`

Is it possible to edit inlineKeyboard to entire media group over bot api?

[Media group example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhoTB.jpg)

Thx